# Kerberos error on external cluster node, with Beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, beeline

I'm currently trying to connect via beeline to a kerberized cluster.

I can do the kinit with my principal (klist confirmes it), but when I try to connect to my Hive Server I get this error.

```
17/11/03 15:52:02 [main]: ERROR transport.TSaslTransport: SASL negotiation failure
javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:212)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslClientTransport.java:94)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:271)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport$1.run(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.client.TUGIAssumingTransport.open(TUGIAssumingTransport.java:49)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:168)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:142)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:207)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1352)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:52)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execCommandWithPrefix(BeeLine.java:1130)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:1169)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execute(BeeLine.java:1002)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:914)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:510)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:493)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5InitCredential.getInstance(Krb5InitCredential.java:147)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:121)
        at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getMechanismContext(Krb5MechFactory.java:187)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getMechanismContext(GSSManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:212)
        at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.initSecContext(GSSContextImpl.java:179)
        at com.sun.security.sasl.gsskerb.GssKrb5Client.evaluateChallenge(GssKrb5Client.java:193)
        ... 35 more
HS2 may be unavailable, check server status
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: (.connection String deleted by me :P.) : GSS initiate failed (state=08S01,code=0)
```

This works like a charm inside the cluster nodes. I can do exactly the same thing inside one of the cluster machines, but not on an outside computer, with a valid KDC ticket.

What am I missing here? We had a similar situation with Oracle ODI, but I think we solved this issue by creating environment variables in the ODI Agent node (that had jars, libs and every conf of Hive and Hadoop).

The error seems to be related with KDC... but I have a valid ticket... so... I'm confused. Remember that I tested the same process inside one of the cluster nodes and it worked perfectly.

(this outside cluster machine is not administrated by me)

Comment: Kerberos auth involves the TGT (obtained with `kinit`), the service ticket for `hive/host.domain`, and possibly intermediate tickets to "hop" from one realm to another via a common, parent realm. So a complete conf in `/etc/krb5.conf` is essential. Enable the debugging flags as explained in GitBook _"Hadoop and Kerberos, the madness beyond the gate"_ section _low-level secrets_ to get a hint of what is missing.

Comment: Please show your beeline connection string

Comment: The problem is not the beeline connection. Cause it works inside the cluster. Ping also works from out to inside so we can reach the node. I can also get a valid ticket. Could it be the krb5.conf that has some sort of problem?